# Is there a iPhone emulator for windows ( or linux ) to install iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I don't have an iPhone but I need to try some iphone apps.

Is there a iPhone emulator for windows ( or linux ) to install iPhone apps ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No iPhone emulator exists, not even for OS X! What you get with the iOS SDK is a simulator only.

Interestingly, I did get several search results for iPhone emulators, but digging deeper they were all:

- spam
- RAD engines such as http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/
- Windows builds of WebKit with an "iPhone" frame around the viewport http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662
- A company claiming they would sell a WINE build for iPhones

Comment: What do you mean, not even for OS X? The iPhone SDK for XCode on Mac OS X comes with an iPhone Simulator. http://d.pr/lzl5

Comment: Simulators are not emulators.

Comment: @Coxy true. You should point that out on the answer body, though.

Comment: Can somebody say what he means by RAD engine? what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get qemu working well enough to install OS X, but last I checked it's not for the faint of heart. You needed to patch qemu (they may have incorporated the necessary patches in current versions, I haven't checked), replace the bootloader on the installer disk image, add a few kexts to the installer disk image (NullCPUPowerManagement, fakesmc), and then after installing add those kexts to the newly-installed system before being able to boot it.

Comment: If you're willing to run an entire OS X installation then would be better to run it in VMWare or VirtualBox in that case, which is much easier and faster.