# Does an iPhone Emulator exist for Windows 7?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to develop a simple iPhone application. However, I do not have the money to buy an actual iPhone. So I'm wonder if there's a good iPhone emulator out there.

I don't want one of those HTML/CSS "emulators" that run websites in iframes. I want something that can actually run Objective-C code.

And yes, I know emulators aren't perfect. I might get an iPhone in the future.

Comment: Objective-C is a *language*. You don't "run" it, you compile a program written in it and run the program. GCC compiles Objective-C, by the way (but that won't help you).

Comment: you can't be a real iOS developer without a Mac+iPhone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a iPhone emulator for windows ( or linux ) to install iPhone apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175183/is-there-a-iphone-emulator-for-windows-or-linux-to-install-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no cheap and legal way of running Xcode, the iOS development environment, on a PC. You do not need an iPhone, but you need an intel-based Mac running OS X. If you plan to do iOS 5 development, your Mac needs to run the version code-named "Lion". Pre-lion version (Snow Leopard) will work too, but the latest version of the Xcode development environment is available only for Lion. The distribution of the development tools includes a very good simulator for iPhone and iPad, which is fully integrated with the development environment.

Comment: i'd like to add that the latest version of Xcode 4.2 is also available for snow leopard not just lion.

Comment: @iNoob Well, if it is, I cannot find it: in fact, I ended up upgrading to Lion just to be able to run the latest version 4.2.1. The latest I could get for the leopard was 4.2.0.

Comment: guess i'm living under a rock, i thought 4.2.0 was latest, sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @iNoob FWIW, I did not notice much change going from 4.2.0 to 4.2.1, so I do not think that you are missing much by not upgrading.

Comment: As soon as you told about 4.2.1 i went to check the changlogs, you're right there aren't much changes from 4.2.0

`What's new in Apple Xcode 4.2.1:
November 17th, 2011
· Fixes an issue where the "Convert to Objective-C ARC" operation would not complete.
· Resolves a problem that resulted in no visible developer profiles in the Organizer.
· Corrects an erroneous locked file dialog appearing in the documentation window.`